# Align Artwork to Artboard in Illustrator via javascript

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator

I'm attempting to position an object in illustrator to the bottom, left of the art board via javascript. I can access the object with javascript and perform function to it like "rotate"

```
if ( app.documents.length > 0) {
    doc = app.activeDocument;
}


   function traceImage(doc) {

         doc.pageItems[0].rotate (30);


}

traceImage(doc);
```

But I'm having trouble finding a simple way to position/align the "pageItems[0]" in the bottom/left of the art board. Is there a simpler approach to this other than calculating it's current distance and then moving it? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Similarly if you're looking to center the item to the artboard, you'd need to handle the height and width a little differently.

```
if ( app.documents.length > 0) {
    doc = app.activeDocument;

    // Get the active Artboard index
    var activeAB = doc.artboards[doc.artboards.getActiveArtboardIndex()];

    // Get the right most X point of the Artboard
    // artboardX + artboardWidth
    var artboardRight = activeAB.artboardRect[0] + activeAB.artboardRect[2];
    // Get the bottom most Y point of the Artboard
    // artboardY + artboardHeight
    var artboardBottom = activeAB.artboardRect[1] + activeAB.artboardRect[3];
   
    // The page item you want to move. Reference it how you will. This just
    // obviously grabs the first pageItem in the document.
    var myPageItem = doc.pageItems[0];

    // Here is where the magic happens. Set the position of the item.
    // [0,0] would be at the top left, so we have to compensate for the    artboard
    // height and width. We add item's height then split it for the vertical
    // offset, or we'd  end up BELOW the artboard.
    // Then we subtract the item's width and split the difference to center the
    // item horizontally.
    var horziontalCenterPosition = (artboardRight - myPageItem.width)/2;
    var verticalCenterPosition = (artboardBottom + myPageItem.height)/2;

    myPageItem.position = [horziontalCenterPosition, verticalCenterPosition];
}
```

Comment: This is a great way of centering. This even considers if the artboard is not set to 0,0

Answer (score 3):

There probably an easier way than this, but this works.

```
if ( app.documents.length > 0) {
    doc = app.activeDocument;

     // Get the active Artboard index
    var activeAB = doc.artboards[doc.artboards.getActiveArtboardIndex()];

    // Get the Height of the Artboard
    var artboardBottom = activeAB.artboardRect[3];

    // The page item you want to move. Reference it how you will. This just
    // obviously grabs the first pageItem in the document.
    var myPageItem = doc.pageItems[0];

    // Here is where the magic happens. Set the poition of the item.
    // [0,0] would be at the top left, so we have to compensate for the artboard
    // height. We add myPageItem's height for offset, or we'd end up BELOW
    // the artboard.
    myPageItem.position = [0, artboardBottom + myPageItem.height];
}
```

Essentially, we have to set the top left corner of our pageItem to the bottom left of the artboard. Unfortunately, that would put our pageItem **below** the Artboard, so we adjust the offset by the height of our pageItem: